# Java String output limiting range of String to Alphabet

Tags: java, string

I'm currently doing an exercise(not homework before anyone gives out) and I am stuck in the final part of the question.

The question is:

```
Write a program which will input a String from the keyboard, output the number of
seperate words, where a word is one or more characters seperated by spaces. Your
program should only count words as groups of characters in the rang A..Z and a..z
```

I can do the first part no problem as you can see by my code:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Exercise10 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter your text: ");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){

        if(input.charAt(i) == ' '){
            counter++;
            }   
    }

    System.out.println(counter + 1);
    keyboard.close();

    }
 }
```

However the part that is confusing me is this:

```
Your program should only count words as groups of characters in the rang A..Z and 
a..z
```

What should I do in this instance?

Comment: you need to lookup regular expressions

Comment: Your way of doing it is wrong. Counting spaces is not the same as counting words. What if user will put `"word<space><space><space>"`?

Comment: Haven't learned regex so I would rather not use until we have been taught it as I don't want to confuse myself.

Comment: @user2830571 - Regex is not difficult bro!!!.. Just have a look.. You will find out that it is specifically made for type of problem you are asking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't give you a full answer but here are two hints.

Instead of counting spaces look at splitting the string and looping through each element from the split:

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Once you have the `String` split and can iterate through the elements, iterate through each character in each element to check if it is alphabetic:

[Hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned I don't want to use Regex for the moment.

Comment: @user2830571 None of those solutions use regex.  Which part do you think requires a regex? I can explain more once I know your assumptions.

Comment: @user2830571 For now, just assume you can pass the String you would like to split on.  For instance, `string.split(" ");` .  Technically, that is a regex for any string exactly matching [space]

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should not consider separate punctuation characters as words. So the phrase `one, two, three !` would have 3 words, even if `!` is separated by space.

Split the string on spaces. For every token, check the characters; if at least one of them is in range `a..z` or `A..Z`, increment counter and get to the next token.

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned I don't want to use Regex for the moment

Comment: There is no regex involved. All you have to do is `phrase.split(" ")` and you get the tokens.